# How to get the column of the beginning of a line in vim script

Tags: vim, whitespace

In vim script, `col("$")` will return the column # of the end of the line. I want something similar to get the column # for the beginning of the line, something like `col("^")`. But that doesn't work, nor can I find anything that does that.

I want this so that I know the amount of white-space at the beginning of a line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
indent(line("."))
```

Answer (score 0):

The best I can come up with right now to do this is

```
normal! ^
col(".")
```

That's not an ideal solution, though, because I'm essentially just moving the cursor where I want and then checking the column.